# nextJS + express: Dynamic route (/some/:id) not found

Tags: reactjs, server-side, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a project with `React` and `nextJS` which provides pre-built images at a path like `http://example.com/img/123ab53424` (fetched from an API, the `123...` part being the uuid returned from the API).

I've built a custom `server.js` (code [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/sschuchlenz/cb5b5834aee03c1eae35a1fc0ee62059)) since SSR isn't working out of the box but my `/img/:id` calls yield 404 errors.

**Update**: I forgot to mention that it is built so that inside `/pages/` there is a `[id].js` file, so I guess my `/img/:id` route doesn't cut it here...

Is there a step missing or something malformed in my `server.js`? Any help appreciated ;)

Comment: can you please share console errors, if any ??

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but you have declared that all your requests should be handled by nextjs here: 
```
server.all('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })
```. So it follows that nextjs will try to look for the the resources in the pages/img directory.

Comment: /pages/img/[id].js if this is your dire you won't have 404 on http://example.com/img/123ab53424 but you defiantly will have 404 0n http://example.com/img. could you plz share some code? It's nothing with serverjs !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all posters, I've refactored my code with `next-routes` and changes to `server.js`, now it works as intended :)